# Is "ReferenceEquals(myObject, null)" better practice than "myObject == null"?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a co-worker who's a fan of writing his null checks as follows:

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(myObject, null))
```

I, on the other hand, find this syntax cumbersome to read and prefer:

```
if (myObject != null)
```

I've found some articles and stack overflow questions discussing the merits of ReferenceEquals with respect to operator overloading, but outside of the operator overloading scenario, is there any benefit to ReferenceEquals vs == ?

Comment: Worth noting that your friend's version is less readable (which becomes an issue when the checks are interchangeable, which they usually are).

Comment: Also - it's worse than above - you have to type `if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(myObject, null))` - so it's even longer than described in reality.

Comment: @ReedCopsey No, you don't have to type that, because your method is inside a class or struct that inherits the static `ReferenceEquals` method from its (direct or indirect) base class `System.Object`. So it's OK to write as above (hiding the inherited method with a `new` method might of course happen, but that's an evil exception).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen True - but it's ugly to leave it out.. If you're being pedantic enough to worry about an improperly overloaded == in every case, you should be wanting to specify it explicitly, too...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Well, you can easily tell if `ReferenceEquals` is hidden (or another overload is defined which matches). But if one should follow your philosophy, one could say `global::System.Object.ReferenceEquals(myObject, null)`, for suppose somone defined other types or namespaces called `Object` and `System` ...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Or just use "object.Ref.." as that's language defined.  My personal philosophy, though, would be to use == :)

Comment: When you _are_ attempting to avoid an overloaded `==` it is probably more readable than `(object)myObject == null`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> but outside of the operator overloading scenario, is there any benefit to ReferenceEquals vs == ?

No - the only advantage (and I'd argue it's not much of an advantage) to explicitly using `Object.ReferenceEquals` would be that it will never use the overloaded operator equals.  In the non-overloaded case, the [== Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is defined to "returns true if its two operands refer to the same object" for all "reference types other than string".  As such, its equivalent (provided its not overloaded).

I, personally, also favor using the second syntax, and find it more maintainable for null checking.  I'd also argue that any overloaded `operator==` should also provide proper checking against `null`, and in the case where it did not for some reason (which would be odd), there'd likely be a specific rationale behind that decision which would cause you to want to use the overload, not `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: "Any overloaded operator== should provide checking for null" - this can only be done with 'ReferenceEquals', right?  Otherwise it's self-referential and you get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 37):

With c# 7, you can use:

```
if ( !(myObject is null) )
```

It's equivalent to

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(myObject, null))
```

Comment: Are you sure?  [The C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#constant-pattern) says "the value of the expression is determined by a call to the static `Object.Equals(expr, constant)` method." and `if ( !(myObject is null) )` translates to `if (myObject != null)` [in SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYYBGA9uQDboCSAzgHICuVVAFOaQFYCmAxgBd0AWwCeAeR4DBASnyFiSgJYAzdO3QBCduKl8h6ZfXQA7VlXnyCSJXeJQA7OkEAnZrwDci+wF8fdgFKTuiqAIZU9F4B/ki+QA).  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42814441

Comment: @Kevinoid - now, that ref says *"For reference types, it uses (object)x == null."*. I think that means it explicitly calls the `object` implementation, which is indeed equivalent to `ReferenceEquals`. (For that matter, that is also what `Object.equals(..)` means - does not use any override.)

Answer (score 5):

Well, if someone were to override the == or != operators they could make them do whatever they wanted.  The could even have it do something real mean like `return true;` or `return false;`.    Additionally, if there is an overloaded operator there's a decent chance that it won't perform as well as `ReferenceEquals` (not guaranteed, and it's probably not enough to matter, but still).

Having said that, since with any sensible implementation of any overloaded operator this is unlikely to be a problem at all.  I personally don't use `ReferenceEquals` unless I have a compelling reason to not use the `==` operator for that type or in that particular instance.

Comment: If the overloaded `==` operator is implemented poorly/improperly, then *that's* the bug that should be fixed. Working around it by using `ReferenceEquals()` isn't the right way to go.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're assuming you have control over the type and therefore have the ability to fix it.  That's not always the case.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The overloaded `==` should definitely be fixed, but I would argue that using `ReferenceEquals()` is solid defensive programming rather than a workaround.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The question specifically states that it's with respect to comparing it with a null literal.  I never stated that `ReferenceEquals` has no place because `==` should have reference semantics, only that a value should only be equal to null when it's actually null in a sensible implementation.

Comment: OK. I read *"I personally don't use ReferenceEquals unless I have a compelling reason to not use the == operator for that type or in that particular instance."* as a more general avoidance of `ReferenceEquals`, and wished to clarify what you were saying.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Needing to perform a reference comparison of non-null values on a type that has overridden `==` to have other semantics *is* a compelling reason to use `ReferenceEquals` instead of `==`, so even in that case the statement still holds true.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of null checks, the two should always return the same results. If a non-null reference ever equals null (even when using the Null Object pattern), regardless of whether ReferenceEquals or the == operator was used, it's a *very* bad thing. So, in that scenario I would use ==/!=.

I would say that, if the == operator were overloaded, using ReferenceEquals *might* be *slightly* faster. The first thing an overloaded == should do is see if the two variables point to the same object, so in the case of an overloaded operator you end up with an extra frame on the call stack. Using ReferenceEquals also guarantees that that's the *only* check performed.

I would generally also use ==/!= in pretty much any other scenario. The entire idea is that the operator defines "equality"; that is not always referential (in fact, most compound objects should be compared structurally for equality; they're equal if their members are equal). The object, theoretically, knows how best to compare itself to another object, for equality, relative order, etc. and so rather than hardcoding a very specific and possibly incorrect piece of logic, you should use the object-oriented nature of the language to let the object tell you whether it's equal to anything else or not.

Comment: Actually, the first thing an overload typically does, is "try-cast" `other` to the same class. If the result is `null`, then it is known to be `not equal`. Nevertheless your point is valid: whatever check is done requires some nested call.

Comment: *"The entire idea is that the operator [don't you mean "the class"?] defines "equality""*. Exactly. So if you want to know **whether two variables refer to the same object**, you **should not** use `==`, you should use `ReferenceEquals`, as that is the purpose of that call. Nevertheless, I agree that `== null` is a special case, that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The VB.NET tag probably shouldn't have been included in this question as it is not otherwise mentioned, but, for completeness, `Is` is equivalent to `Object.ReferenceEquals` and so can always be used instead of that call.

Answer (score 1):

So, I wanted to chime in on this conversation even though it's a million years old.

Lets's say we want to write an extension method that checks for null. We could do the following:

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T value) where T : class, new()
{ 
   return value == null;
}
```

but this code is boring.

The reason why is that T has to be a class. Why? Because we can't compare value types with null. Which makes writing decent generic code a big pain.

Alternatively you can attach the same method to object and never care what that object is.

```
public static bool IsNull(this object value)
{
   return object.ReferenceEquals(value, null);
}
```

This opens other possibilities like of writing fault tolerant monads for Linq for example or what have you - without actually constraining your generic code.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I believe you are incorrect. The 'this' keyword in the context of the example defines an Extension method on an existing class, this case the 'object' class which everything inherits from. The above method will work and not throw an exception. IE, `string str = null; if (str.IsNull()) // do something` will work. The compiler will know that the string class does not have a 'IsNull' function, but will also know that you have defined an extension method. So then the compiler calls IsNull(str), which then calls the static ReferenceEquals method on the object class.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Additional reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Edit ps: I personally like defining extension methods for cases where I want to do something AND handle the variable being null, becuase I can still call the extension method even if the variable is null, and then in the extension method first check for null, handle it, and then do whatever other simple logic I wanted to short cut into what looks like a function call on the original class object.

Comment: @B.O.B. - bah, I could have sworn I tested that, years ago. BUT what I had tested involved calling `this.somefunc()` - here `value.somefunc()` - *inside* the extension method - that caused the exception, not the original extension call. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceEquals might be slightly faster. As mentioned before it makes sure that no overloaded Equals operator is being called. Also ReferenceEquals ensures only one comparison is performed instead of possibly 2 depending on the implementation of the overloaded Equals operator. Although it's very likely that the overloaded operator is using ReferenceEquals itself as the first statement.

I personally do use ReferenceEquals, but only on places where I am really tweaking to squeeze out the last clock cycles (places that are possibly called millions of times per second). Or when I have no control over the type, like in the case of generics. ... But again only when performance is really critical.

Comment: Keep in mind that operators are not virtual.  It is the *compile time type* that matters, not the runtime type.  In the case of generics, unless there is a constraint to a type that overloads the `==` operator, the use of `==` will always result in the `object` overload being used, which needs to do no checks and simply calls `ReferenceEquals`.  In those cases it will not only be functionally equivalent, but the performance will be virtually identical as well.  This makes generics one of the *safest* times to use `==` rather than `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @Servy - wait, what?  Isn't `(object) ==` defined to call `Equals` method of the first parameter? Isn't the point of defining `Equals` method, in a custom class, to override that equality test?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it doesn't *just* call `object.Equals`.  It will do null checks and if both are non-null *then* it will use the virtual `object.Equals` to determine the result.  Since one value being passed in is null, we know that won't happen here.

Answer (score 0):

Really, really late reply - but I hit the article when I was reading the EFCore library and came across this method...

There is a Check class in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities that uses this logic for a null check....

```
        internal static class Check
    {
        [ContractAnnotation("value:null => halt")]
        public static T NotNull<T>([NoEnumeration] T value, [InvokerParameterName] [NotNull] string parameterName)
        {
#pragma warning disable IDE0041 // Use 'is null' check
            if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
#pragma warning restore IDE0041 // Use 'is null' check
            {
                NotEmpty(parameterName, nameof(parameterName));

                throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the other answers, the semantic of the two calls is a little different.

In case you want to use the semantic of `ReferenceEquals` but with simplified syntax, for **reference types** you can also use:

```
if (myObject is object)
```

Answer (score 0):

With C# 9, you can use `if (myObject is not null)`. [The reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) states the following safety guarantee:

> When you match an expression against null, the compiler guarantees that no user-overloaded == or != operator is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

A decade after the accepted answer was originally written, the correct thing is now *neither* of those.

Instead, for `null` checks, use `is null` or `is not null`.

But in the body of your question you also asked a broader questions:

> is there any benefit to `ReferenceEquals` vs `==`?

The huge benefit is that actually wanting *address* equality is rare.  So I would say you should write it using `ReferenceEquals` for emphasis, and make it clear that it's not just a mistake where you forgot to override `operator==`.

Really, I wish it was a C# compiler or IDE warning if you implemented `IEquatable<T>` and *didn't* override `operator==`.  Or an opt-in warning to just disallow non-overridden `operator==` entirely, since that's *so* much more often a mistake than it is that I actually wanted same-address.