# Pattern matching equal null vs is null

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

From Microsoft new-features-in-c-7-0:

```
public void PrintStars(object o)
{
    if (o is null) return;     // constant pattern "null"
    if (!(o is int i)) return; // type pattern "int i"
    WriteLine(new string('*', i));
}
```

Whats the diferrence of `o == null` and `o is null`?

Comment: Please consider marking the accepted answer here for future readers. The most voted answer is currently wrong and this can be very confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `o is null` is translated to `object.Equals(null, o)` (you can see it [here](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMAAoAnSMjjIaEkAAoBRAFapyyGAICU7Tm1ydjMMADMYymAF5rMCMBIkdMCamTAJEHEZMdzlirqmgB0AEqoZqhuEOSoAKIAjsA0JEoCADT2js4ubh5ePn7+FspqGsghSSlpig5OWbp57p7e+n4BVmAM9c6uLYXtJp0AhF0M0qY6zQXeMAD08zDICPioXDTIaF4wAESTYLtDxowCECACJKghAOpSaAAykKh1qADuMChS0IoA5ABUvyyYGmRU4AF88OCgA==)).

The `object.Equals` code [is written as](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Object.cs/):

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB)
{
    if (objA == objB)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (objA == null || objB == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

so in the end there will be a `o == null` (the first `if`). Note that `System.Object` doesn't define the `operator==`, so the one used is the one for reference types that is reference equality.

Theorically, by watching the called code, one could think that `o == null` (with `o` a `System.Object`) should be faster than `o is null` (less operations)... But who knows? :-)

The end result is that, through two different routes, `o is null` and `o == null` (with `o` a `System.Object`) return the same result.

By looking we can even see that `o == null` is the same as `object.ReferenceEquals(o, null)` (with `o` a `System.Object`) :-).

**the interesting question should be, why doesn't the C# compiler translates the `x is null` to `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`?**. Note that, thanks to how the boxing of nullable types is done, it would work even for:

```
int? a = null;
if (a is null) { /* */ }
```

**changes to the compiler made this response invalid... If you click on the "here" link you can see it**

Comment: `o == null` is not guaranteed to be the same as `Object.ReferenceEquals(o, null)`, because the `==` operator can be overridden. So while that is true for the type `object`, it is not true always.

Comment: @Abion47 The only place where I didn't repeat the *with `o` a `System.Object`* boilerplate :-) Fixed.

Comment: Saying that it's true for a `System.Object` is misleading though, since the only way you can actually have an instance of type `Object` is by doing `Object o = new Object()` (which I have no idea why anyone would actually do). In actuality, any "object" passed to `Object.Equals` would be of a type that *inherits* from `Object` but may or may not have its own override for `==`.

Comment: @Abion47 BUT note that the `operator==` isn't virtual, and the question was explicitly about a method that receives an `object` as the parameter.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't emit a call to `object.Equals(null, o)`, or at least not today; switch the result side on your SharpLab page to "IL" to see... it just emits CIL that chooses what to do based on whether or not the given variable is "false".  This is the same CIL that gets emitted when you use `object.ReferenceEquals` or `==`.  Oddly enough, `object.Equals` is the only C# pattern I tried that **doesn't** just `brtrue.s` over the conditional code.

Comment: @JoeAmenta They probably changed something in the compiler.

Answer (score 11):

Since the answer of @xanatos is outdated (but that is only mentioned at the very end) I'm writing a new one, because I wanted to know this as well and researched it.

**In short:** if you don't overload the `==` operator, then `o == null` and `o is null` are the same.
If you do overload the `==` operator, then `o == null` will call that, but `o is null` **won't**.

`o is null` always does the same as `ReferenceEquals(o, null)`, i.e. it **only** checks if the value is null, it doesn't call any operators or `Equals` methods.

**Longer answer:** [here is a SharpLab sample](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1MpcudYsrQDsZKBZABT0A9gEpG7VqzQAzSoJFcolbgFcMGMUxLS9HAOyUCAbil6AvuelyFAeWAArOAGMYAOgBKcWYjjcXOABRAEc1CAwoRSRVDS1ta31qIzwzXSSrdP1bRUoAXjzYzQSspJYcI3I0ssyynIdnN3dQ8MjoovidMukKygAWaozE8qMABkGWWtZzThwCADZKYBERDEoRAAdECBgRBALhSgAPGPoATwk8gD51p1cPFoiok4uTNlLZhaWVtc3t3YQAEI8ocTnRKBd8jdAYIjgVXqQLEA===) that showcases the various ways to check for null.

If you view the result in IL form you see that:

- `is null` and `ReferenceEquals` result in the same code
- `o == null` will call the overloaded `operator==`
- `object.Equals(o, null)` calls that method
- if you comment the `operator==` in class `C` you will see that `o == null` now produces the same code as `o is null`

Answer (score -6):

The differences between "is" and ==  is "is" special that it act as == if you compare to value and act as typeof(type) when you compare type of object to type.