# is nullcheck with keyword "is" safe?

Tags: c#, null-check

I, in a hurry, typed the following code:

```
List<Foo> myList = feedMyList();
var bar = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => something);

if (bar is null)
{
    // something
}
```

My first thought was that I was writing something wrong, so I experienced a bit with C# interactive:

```
> var list = new List<string>();
> list.FirstOrDefault()
null
> list.FirstOrDefault() is null
true // As expected
> list.Add("abcdef");
> list.FirstOrDefault() is null
false // As expected
> list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Length > 120) is null
true // As expected
```

and everything was correct. Is it safe to write (and use) `if (bar is null)` or am I missing potential issues?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (bar == null)`? but afaik there should be no trouble using `is` here.

Comment: I think you will find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814245/pattern-matching-equal-null-vs-is-null

Comment: You mean [What is the difference between “x is null” and “x == null”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40676426/993547).

Comment: @PatrickHofman totally, my bad.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it is hard to find duplicates. We as experienced users know that.